# Problema al cargar librería JAR con NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy tratando de usar la librería **Jackson Core** en **Netbeans 8.2**. Después de cargar la librería, mi aplicación no encuentra las clases al hacer los ***imports***.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: dale click derecho

Comment: fix import y listo

Comment: te cargara la libreria completa

Comment: No funciona, solo hace un sonido tipo pitido.

Comment: como?, no deberia de hacer eso como que un pitido?

Comment: @Critical Ghost un pitido, un sonido de campana, no se, un sonido corto del sistema como que no hace na.

Comment: mmmmm eso si que es muy raro, no deberia de hacer un pitido osea no es raro

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: eso es una clase de java? si es eso, no se puede modificar nunca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conseguí cargar una biblioteca siguiendo las indicaciones de éste vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_P1wGPuG-Q

Es una versión más antigua de Netbeans, en otro idioma y usa otra librería, pero me sirvió.

Explico lo que hice paso a paso:

**1º. Descargar librería**

*Cambie de librería*, de **Jackson** a **FlexJson**, mas sencilla. Te quitas los problemas de saber si te bajaste el paquete correcto.

Creo una carpeta de nombre FlexJson en el directorio donde almaceno librerías para Java (dentro del equipo) y dejo dentro los ficheros de la librería.

> **FlexJson:**
>
> Documentación:  http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html
>
> Página oficial: http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/

**2º. Cree una biblioteca nueva en Netbeans.**
Menu Herramientas > Librerías
Botón "New Library..."
La nombro con FlexJson:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**3º. Agregar los ficheros JAR**

Tenemos 3 pestañas: Ruta de clases, Fuentes y Javadoc. En cada una se cargan ficheros diferentes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta librería solo tiene tres ficheros.

> **flexjson-2.1.JAR** se carga en la pestaña "Ruta de clases".
>
> **flexjson-2.1-javadoc.JAR** se carga en la pestaña "Javadoc".
>
> **flexjson-2.1-sources.JAR** en la pestaña "Fuentes".

Pulsamos el botón "Aceptar". Ahora **la librería fue añadida a Netbeans, falta añadirla al proyecto** para su uso.

> ***Nota:** si la librería tuviera más ficheros JAR, los cargaremos todos en una u otra pestaña atendiendo a si estan nombrados con las palabras sources, javadoc o con ninguna de ellas.*

**4º. Añadir la librería a nuestro proyecto.**

En nuestro árbol del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hacemos clic derecho sobre **"Bibliotecas"**. Seleccionamos **"Agregar biblioteca..."**.
Aparece la siguiente ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Seleccionar la biblioteca FlexJson** y pulsar **"Add Library"**.

Y esto es todo. Un poco complicado teniendo en cuenta que **Netbeans ofrece varias opciones que no nos van a funcionar de ninguna manera**, como las de añadir directamente un JAR/Carpeta y que se pueden crear librerías metiendo dentro "cualquier" cosa.

Comment: Es muy ilustrativo lo que nos comentas. Solo deseo agregar que si el proyecto fuera un proyecto Maven o Gradle no habria necesidad de ir al sitio del proveedor, descargar manualmente el jar y agregarlo al IDE. Esto lo harían Maven o Gradle por ti.

Comment: Igual considera aceptar tu propia respuesta